# I have a dropdown displaying user names. How can I use Ajax to display their info?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My dropdown list displays user names that I get from the database. I want to implement a `displayInfo` function so that when someone selects a user, it will automatically display his/her info below.

How can I display a user's info when someone selects their name?

This is my dropdown code:

```
<?php 
//connect                                                 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","123abc");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "users");

//query
$sql= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT person_id,first_name FROM users");

echo "<select name='dropdown' onchange='displayInfo' id='dropdown'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))     
{
    //display friends' first names on dropdown
    if($row['person_id'] == $row['first_name']) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['person_id'] . "' selected>" . $row['list_name'] . "</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['person_id'] . "'>" . $row['first_name'] . "</option>";
    }

}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: description rewritten, code formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to call a Javascript function on option select like this

```
<?php 
//connect                                                 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","123abc");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "users");

//query
$sql= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT person_id,first_name FROM users");

echo "<select name='dropdown' onchange='displayInfo' id='dropdown'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))     
{
    //display friends' first names on dropdown
    if($row['person_id'] == $row['first_name']) {
        **echo "<option onchange='myFunction(this);' value='" . $row['person_id'] . "' selected>" . $row['list_name'] . "</option>";**
    } else {
        echo "<option onchange='myFunction(this);' value='" . $row['person_id'] . "'>" . $row['first_name'] . "</option>";
    }

}
echo "</select>";

<script>
function myFunction(control){

$(control).val() //to access value or any other functionality
}
</script>
```

Comment: @yan777dro Please accept the ans it will be helpfull :)